# Redirect from cook search engine to mysite

Tags: php, redirect, search-engine

My cooking site is indexed by a cook search engine as above example

```
http://mysitename/content.php?r=101-post1%29-test-20%
http://mysitename/content.php?r=102-post1%250-test2-31%
http://mysitename/content.php?r=103-post1%102-test3-40%
```

etc...

My site has all this posts in the following form:

```
http://mysitename/post1%29-test-20%
http://mysitename/post2%29-test-20%
http://mysitename/post3%29-test-20%
```

Is it possible to make a content.php file to redirect all of these references from cook search engine to my site real post?

EDIT: Thank you for your answer but by mistake i forget to mention that me host provider has lightpd server and .htaccess is useless. Any other solution?

---

EDIT2: I have tested the second option but no luck again.
I realised that the problem is the url because the query from search engine is like:

```
http://mysitename/content.php?r=153-Χημική-δίαιτα-πολλών-κιλών
```

and it is in greek language

---

EDIT 3

I test this code:

```
<?php
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:./". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit;
?>
```

who produce the following result:

```
http://mysitename/r=153-Χημική-δίαιτα-πολλών-κιλών
```

is there a way to remove the "r=153-" and leave the rest url "Χημική-δίαιτα-πολλών-κιλών" ?
like:

```
http://mysitename/Χημική-δίαιτα-πολλών-κιλών
```

That would be a perfect solution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Save the following as an .htaccess file in root web directory:

```
Options  +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
Order deny,allow

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /content.php?r=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess (at the root):

```
Options  +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
Order deny,allow


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=([\d]+)-(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?content\.php$ /content/%2 [L,R=301]
```

This will remove the r=NUMBER-post...

You can test it here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/